# i keep getting "Error converting data type nvarchar to int" on asp application but works fine in desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have this as stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[editUserInfo] 
(@userid int, @firstName varchar(50), @lastName varchar(50), @contact varchar(50), @address varchar(50), @info varchar(100), @username varchar(50), @password varchar(50), @rid int)
as 
update dbo.userLogin
set u_firstName=@firstName, u_lastName=@lastName, u_contact=@contact, u_address=@address, u_info=@info, u_username=@username, u_password=@password, r_id=@rid
where u_id=@userid
```

i have following code

when `save` button is clicked following event is trriggered

```
protected void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  String i = Session["id"].ToString();
  userInfo usr = new userInfo();
  usr.setFirstName(firstNameTxt.Text);
  usr.setLastName(lastNameTxt.Text);
  usr.setAddress(addressTxt.Text);
  usr.setContact(contactTxt.Text);
  usr.setInfo(infoTxt.Text);
  usr.setRole(rolebox.SelectedValue);
  usr.setUserName(userNameTxt.Text);
  usr.setPassword(passwordTxt.Text);
  usr.setId(i);

  userEditService usredit = new userEditServiceImp();

  Boolean ok = usredit.editUserInfo(usr);
  if (ok == true)
  {
    Response.Redirect("viewUser.aspx");
  }
  else
  {
    String msg = "error occured";
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
  }
}
```

the code to handle the database is as follows

```
public Boolean editUserInfo(userInfo u)
{
  String fn = u.getFirstName();
  String ln = u.getLastName();
  String add = u.getAddress();
  String cont = u.getContact();
  String un = u.getUserName();
  String pass = u.getPassword();
  String info = u.getInfo();
  String r = u.getRole();
  String i = u.getId();

  int rid = Convert.ToInt16(r);
  int id = Convert.ToInt16(i);

  try
  {
     dbConnection dbcon = new dbConnection();
     con = dbcon.doConnection();

     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.CommandText = "editUserInfo";
     cmd.Connection = con;

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName",fn);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName",ln);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact",cont);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",add);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@info",info);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",un);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",pass);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rid",rid);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId",id);

     if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
     {
       return true;
     }
     else
     {
       return false;
     }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
   }
   finally
   {
     con.Close();
   }
   return false;
 }
```

thus `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` keeps on catching the exception and it goes like this"`Error converting data type nvarchar to int"`. i tried the same code for desktop application and it works fine...without any errors or exception.

so i would like you guys to help me solve this problem.
i will be very helpful.
thanks in advance too...

Comment: Do you use another DB for desktop use? My guess is that in you defined a DB field differently.

Answer (score 5):

For OleDbCommand, I think that the parameters should be added in the order they appear in the stored procedure.

You could try moving "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId",id);" to be the first parameter.

Comment: thanks paul...i never knew this could be the error.. i hope i can be of help to you too